# Flow triggers Email Alert, but no email sent in Logs, no email received

Tags: visual-workflow, process-builder, email-template, administration

I created a new Flow that runs on Update of our Custom Object. When the record is updated with a new Assigned_to__c user, it should trigger an Email Alert with Classic Email Template.

[image]
[image]

The Decision Router is working perfectly; however, the user never receives the email. I've tested several times, not only with the Flow Debugger.

Furthermore, the logs show the email has not been sent. I obscured the email address here; it is the correct email address.

[image]

Comment: are you running in an org with email deliverability = System rather than All?

Comment: Can you share the entire screens shot which you have debugged so we can see the outputs at each level

Comment: @SaiPraveenKakkirala Yes, see new screenshots. Thank you :)

Comment: @cropredy Deliverability is "All email"

Comment: @RyanMcNeely I don't see any issue in the debug logs. Did you check if the email alert and template were configured correctly.

Comment: I just heard from my Success Manager at SFDC, some of their internal people say this has happened to others. Not clear yet if it's a bug or not. I'll update soon. @SaiPraveenKakkirala

Comment: Experiencing a very similar issue. Is your email alert for a record that is in an active approval process (i.e. waiting for approval)?

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem, turned out the Email Alert was configured to send to specific Users and the user that triggered the Flow did not have Read access to User records other than their own so the Email Alert could get no email addresses.  No error was raised, just stumbled on the solution after hours of debugging - even a blind squirrel finds an acorn every now and then!